# KTOR MultiPartFormDataContent request is very slow

Tags: kotlin, multipartform-data, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I need to perform hundreds of thousands multipart requests per hour containing either Form elements or File elements. Each request has 2 parts and the total size of the request is around 30kb but may range up to 20meg. I am testing with requests no larger than 30kb. My post method looks like this:

var partData:PartData = getThePartData()

```
client.post("endpoint") {
    headers(myHeaders)
    setBody(MultiPartFormDataContent(partData,boundary,contentType))
}
```

on the recieving endpoint I have

```
post("endpointThat Performs BAD!!!!") {
   call.recieveMultipart().readAll().forEach {
     // do somthing trivial
   }
}
```

Or here is endpoint that performes as expected:

```
post("endpointThat Performs BAD!!!!") {
   call.recieve<String>.also{
     // do somthing trivial
   }
}
```

Now in the first Example I recieve a latency of around 400ms.
In the second example I almost do not recieve any latency.

In an attempt to tune the case where I use call.recieveMultipart() I also sat the property

```
 io.ktor.http.content.multipart.skipTempFile to true
```

The effect was minimal

I have tryed with two clients CIO and OkHttp, no difference.

Why is **recieveMultipart** so slow ? How can I fix it ?

Just to give som digits to get the picture. When using recieveMultipart 272 requests take 120 000ms, recieve takes 30 000 miliseconds. Around 4 times difference.

**UPDATE:**
There seams to be siginificant performance difference between

```
call.recieveMultipart().readAll()
```

and

```
call.recieveMultipart().forEachPart() {}
```

Comment: Can you please file an issue here (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KTOR) with a code snippet for reproduction attached?